# application in screen sometimes gives characters at wrong location

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a character bases application in a telnet session. To allow reattaching of lost connections i use screen. But sometime i get character at wrong screen-location.

The application is 8 rows by 20 colums. It seems that it is simply to refreshing correctly.

Is this related to automargin problem? or any other ide

Comment: Are you sure it is related to screen? What happens without screen?

Comment: without screen everything updates fine